# How to simply load a ML model without retraining it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, computer-vision

I trained a CNN on 30,000 images and want to load the model. The model is named "emotion_recognition_model.h5". Every time I try to call the model, it begins to be retrained. How do I just load it without retraining it? Here is the code for training the model:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import ELU
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, SGD, Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras import regularizers
from keras.regularizers import l1

num_classes = 7
img_rows, img_cols = 48, 48
batch_size = 512

train_data_dir = "/Users/../Behavior/images/train"
validation_data_dir = "/Users/../Behavior/images/validation"


val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=30,
    shear_range=0.3,
    zoom_range=0.3,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(48, 48),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical"
)
validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(48, 48),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical"
)

print(validation_generator.class_indices)

class_labels = validation_generator.class_indices
class_labels = {v: k for k, v in class_labels.items()}
classes = list(class_labels.values())
print(class_labels)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001),input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(7, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(7, kernel_size=(4, 4), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

model.add(Activation("softmax"))

filepath = os.path.join("./emotion_detector_models/model_v6_{epoch}.hdf5")

checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("best_model.hdf5",
                                             monitor='val_accuracy',
                                             verbose=1,
                                             save_best_only=True,
                                             mode='max')
callbacks = [checkpoint]
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])
nb_train_samples = 28709
nb_validation_samples = 3589
epochs = 150
model_info = model.fit(
            train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
            epochs=epochs,
            callbacks=callbacks,
            validation_data=validation_generator,
            validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)


model.save('emotion_recognition_model.h5')
print("Saved model")
```

training with the above code took like 24+ hours so I'd like to simply be able to load the model instead. Here is the code for where I am trying to load the model:

```
from emotion_recognition_model_file import train_generator, class_labels
from keras.models import load_model
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

try:
    classifier = load_model("/Users/TomSmith/Desktop/Vrify/DELPHI/Behavior/emotion_recognition_model.h5")
except:
    try:
        classifier = load_model("/Users/TomSmith/Desktop/Vrify/DELPHI/Behavior/best_model.hdf5")
    except:
        print('e')

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("/Users/TomSmith/Desktop/Vrify/DELPHI/Behavior/haarcascade_eye.xml")


def face_detector(img):
    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    if faces == ():
        return (0, 0, 0, 0), np.zeros((48, 48), np.uint8), img

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    try:
        roi_gray = cv2.resize(roi_gray, (48, 48), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    except:
        return (x,w,y,h), np.zeros((48, 48), np.uint8), img
    return (x,w,y,h), roi_gray, img

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    rect, face, image = face_detector(frame)
    if np.sum([face]) != 0.0:
        roi = face.astype("float") / 255.0
        roi = img_to_array(roi)
        roi = np.expand_dims(roi, axis=0)

        # make a prediction on the ROI, then lookup the class
        preds = classifier.predict(roi)[0]
        label = class_labels[preds.argmax()]
        label_position = (rect[0] + int((rect[1] / 2)), rect[2] + 25)
        cv2.putText(image, label, label_position, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    else:
        cv2.putText(image, "No Face Found", (20, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    cv2.imshow('All', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13:  # 13 is the Enter Key
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm also going to add threading for the cv2 code, but I can't simply load the model. What should I do?

EDIT:
Screenshot of how I know it is retraining
[image: Ran the first code and this is the beginning output]

Comment: Why do you think it is getting retrained?

Comment: @AniketBote it starts going through the training process again (i.e. epoch 1/150)

Comment: Is the loading code in a new file?

Comment: @AniketBote no, it is an output when I run the first code

Comment: What do you mean by it is an output?

Comment: @AniketBote I edited the post to show you

Comment: If you run the first part the model will start training. Either comment the `model.fit()` or use a separate file for the second part. As far as I can tell you can use a different file for second part of the code without any issues.

Comment: @AniketBote so instead of trying to load the model, just use model.fit() ?

Comment: NO!!. You don't have to use `model.fit()` once the model is trained. Just create a new file and copy-paste the code of second part into that and run the file.

Comment: @AniketBote I already did that. I have the model in my directory. I just need to load it and fit it to the real-time data

Comment: We **don't fit** the model with new data, we use `model.predict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder you want to ask about "how to save a model after training?", right?
I see you using Keras, which you choose Tensorflow as its backend, to train your model. So maybe you can use

```
from keras.model import load_model
# save model,assuming "model" is the name of the your instance,give a name as parameter
model.save("name.h5")
#load model
model = load_model("name.h5")
```

Perhaps you can also use some methods coming from Tensorflow not Keras to feed your requirements. I am not sure about that.
I hope it can be helpful, good luck!

Comment: this doesn't work. I've already tried it. Thanks for trying, though.